# Notepad++ regex - Trim leading and trailing whitespace between xml tags

Tags: xml, tags, notepad++

Been hitting my head on this one - I want to match leading and trailing whitespace between xml tags

```
<tag>  fdsfdsf fdsf fds f     </tag>

and end with 

<tag>fdsfdsf fdsf fds f</tag>
```

It should match any opening and closing tag. Thanks for any help. I'll keep reading as well.

EDIT: Here's my research for whoever downvoted the question : (This doesn't work 100% which is why I didn't post it) Search: (<[^<>]+>)([^\s]+)([\s]+)(]+>) 
Replace : \1\3\4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find What: `(<(\w+)>)\s*(.*?)\s*(</\2>)`

Replace with: `$1$3$4`

EDIT: first version didn't work for any tag and used look ahead/behind.  This seems to be a better solution.

EDIT2: Added `\s*` to search for all whitespace instead of just spaces.

---

```
(<(\w+)>)
```

Capture group 1 is the opening tag.  Capture group 2 is the tag name, we use it later to match against the end tag.

```
(.*?)
```

Capture group 3 is between the tags and space.  The `?` forces this group to match lazily, so the outside `\s*` patterns take precedence.

```
(</\2>)
```

Capture group 4 is the end tag, using a back-reference to group 2.

Comment: How do I make it match any tag as well?

Comment: Closest I got so far to replace trailing space is (<[^<>]+>)([^\s]+)([\s]+)(</[^<>]+>)

Comment: and replace with \1\2\4

Comment: I edited my answer shortly after posting.  It will currently match every set of matching tags. Is that not what you want?  Did you refresh and see my edit?

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!